# Yahoo openid check_authentication returning is_valid: false

Tags: php, curl, openid, yahoo, urlencode

Yahoo openid `check_authentication` always returning `is_valid:false` 
am I missing some parameters ?

```
https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth?
openid.assoc_handle=xAS_t.4jTdUdsshHxy2bcoP4XRDBZ3JtfMwc2Otwbw0V3AhEVUg9FF0t.1jZp65mk8Oqf8ZypMZlRMWLP1_Yj44SO16NTlq9cmOq1ls_evue_5ltKPQDMAJo7gNrKe8-
&openid.claimed_id=https://me.yahoo.com/a/CHxd29Etm54Hzrq4_oQ_RSiba_x.k4uA#47ac6
&openid.identity=https://me.yahoo.com/a/CHxd29Etm54Hzrq4_oQ_RSiba_x.k4uA
&openid.mode=check_authentication
&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
&openid.op_endpoint=https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth
&openid.response_nonce=2012-04-05T07:23:23ZsCfrX0VBTKMuHhly34RkZH_wnq887IVClA--
&openid.return_to=http://voxiternal.com/bong/open/verify/yahoo
&openid.signed=assoc_handle,claimed_id,identity,mode,ns,op_endpoint,response_nonce,return_to,signed,pape.auth_level.nist
&openid.pape.auth_level.nist=0
&openid.sig=eymoRtkcrb2EbQVAlF+DdbAb2oM=
&openid.realm=http://voxiternal.com
```

My `check_authentication` is working perfectly with Google. But not with Yahoo.
First I tried with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` which worked with Google but not with Yahoo. Then I tried to change it to GET Params but its still not working

I am attaching my PHP code for `check_authentication`

```
public static function authenticate($request){
    $keys = explode(',', $request['openid_signed']);
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $params['openid.'.$key] = $request['openid_'.str_replace('.', '_', $key)];
    }
    $params['openid.ns']           = $request['openid_ns'];
    $params['openid.signed']       = $request['openid_signed'];
    $params['openid.sig']          = $request['openid_sig'];
    $params['openid.assoc_handle'] = $request['openid_assoc_handle'];
    $params['openid.mode']         = 'check_authentication';
    $params['openid.claimed_id']   = $request['openid_claimed_id'];
    $url = $request['openid_op_endpoint'];
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $res_buff = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $res_buff, 2);
    while(strpos($headers,"100 Continue")!==false){
        list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $body , 2);
    }
    $headers = self::disect($headers);
    $body = self::disect($body);
    if(!isset($headers['HTTP/1.1 200 OK']))
        return -2;
    if(!isset($body['is_valid']))
        return 0;
    return $body['is_valid'];
}
```

-> This solution is functioning properly with all openid providers. just the check_authentication is not working with Yahoo. so I am not willing to make all other parts unstable and move to some openid library

**EDIT**

after hours of struggle It looks like **Its Yahoo who has a problem** with `check_authentication` at the moment as It worked few days ago. However verifying `hmac_sha1` with signature works. but `check_authentication` always returns false through it works with google,aol.

It will be nice If somebody can do a `check_authentication` NOT signature verification with their tools/libraries.

Comment: Why do you think using a well-tested openid library is less stable than your self-written code?! [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) is often a bad idea.

Comment: well I've already used My self written `OpenIDClient` class in several places. and `associate` `checkid_setup` are working perfectly. will ALL(Well Tested google,yaho,aol,orange....) openid provider. just the `check_authentication` is not working with Yahoo. So It is easier to just fix `check_authentication` part of my self written code than rewriting the whole login system with another library. and I believe fixing it will not be a mess. as its probabbly some missing parameter problem. which is easy to fix. ONCE FOUND

Comment: @DiproSen: Nobody hinders you from debugging and fixing your own code. But why must this be on Stackoverflow? What's the use for the community here? Have you even published your openid library to the public?

Comment: Yes I'll. Its currently in github public repo

Comment: @DiproSen: I suggest you link it with your question then, so it's clear about which library this is.

Comment: Thats too small. and far minimalistic. People will laugh at it.

Comment: Please Check Edit (Last lines).